# CException: Контроллер не может найти представление

Tags: php, yii

Выдаётся такая ошибка:

> CException Контроллер SiteController не может найти представление "site/error". (Z:\home_avtomat_new_1\www\framework\web\CController.php:878)

Хотя в `SiteController` есть `actionError`. В чем дело и как можно настроить оформление для этого?

это произошло после того как я добавил в Controller функцию удалюящую повторения страниц:

```
public function init()
{
    $request = Yii::app()->request->requestUri;
    $code = 404;
    $message = 'Страница не найдена';

    // Проверяем, если есть в урле index.php или ?r=, то кидаем 404 ошибку
    if ((strpos($request, 'index.php') !== false) || (strpos($request, '?r=') !== false) || (strpos($request, 'index') !== false))
    {
        // Если это не контроллер по-умолчанию, то кидаем 404 ошибку обычным способом
        if (Yii::app()->controller->id !== Yii::app()->defaultController)
            throw new CHttpException($code, $message);
        // если идентификатора записи не существует



        // Отображаем стандартное представление ошибки
        $this->render(Yii::app()->errorHandler->errorAction, array(
            'code' => $code,
            'message'=> $message
        ));
        // Если это контроллер по-умолчанию, кидаем 404 ошибку необычным способом.
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
         //throw new CHttpException(404,'Указанная запись не найдена');    
        // Выходим из приложения
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Тебе же пишет, что SiteController не может найти представление (вид или вьюха), а не action.
Проверил свой каталог views? Есть скрипт в директории views/site/error.php?
И я не уверен, что если ты добавил в СController код, то оно ищет именно в той директории вьюху.
2) Если ты добавил свою функцию  в СController (имхо, я никакой явной функции не вижу, разве что сторонний код внутри метода init()), учти что добавлять в core-файлы фреймворка свой код - дурной тон. Например ты захочешь обновить версию фреймворка и куда потом денется твой код?
Наследуйся или переопределяй методы core-классов.